# Eclipse: Dynamic web project convert library to maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

We have a project used Dynamic Web Project,
And we want to convert to maven project.
I want to ask is it possible to convert the `jar` files under `/Web-INF/lib`  to maven ??

I only know the method to add dependency use maven.
And I want to ask is there better idea
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

converting your web project into maven will only change the structure and nature of your existing project. You have to provide the dependencies in pom.xml file. Otherwise, How else maven would locate and add the jars.
Please refer:
  [1]: http://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/  [2]: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-java-web-project-to-maven-project/